# using Button and Timer Simultaneously in java

Tags: java, sockets

I have two buttons and and Timer. When I run the code it gets connected to the Socket. For every 1000 milliseconds timer should send the command(message) to the Socket and simultaneously when I click a button it should send other message as in the code. But problem is that when I click a button either the messages which are sent are delayed or messages are not sent properly through dat is the receiving end is not receiving properly.
How to handle this issue?

Here is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            configure config=new configure();
            config.run();
            config.setVisible(true);                
        }
    });
}

protected void run() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

     try {
         connection.setText("Connected to < NONE >");
        socket=new Socket("192.168.1.3",3000);
//      System.out.println("Connection Established") ;
        connection.setText("CONNECTION ESTABLISHED WITH : " + "< " + 
                            socket.getInetAddress() + " >" + "\n");

    } catch (UnknownHostException e)
     {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
     catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    //  System.out.println("connection failed");
        connection.setText("CONNECTION FAILED");
    }
}

public configure()
{
    setResizable(false);
    setBounds(300,80,800,600);
    contentPane=new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    configlabel=new JLabel("CONFIGURE YOUR MODEL");
    configlabel.setBounds(210,20,500,40);
    configlabel.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,28));
    contentPane.add(configlabel);

    connection=new JLabel();
    connection.setBounds(12,80,500,40);
    connection.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,16));
    contentPane.add(connection);

    channel1=new JLabel("Channel 1");
    channel1.setBounds(80, 140, 80, 30);
    channel1.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,15));
    contentPane.add(channel1);

    channel1Field=new JTextField();
    channel1Field.setBounds(55, 200, 120, 30);
    channel1Field.setEnabled(true);     
    contentPane.add(channel1Field);

    channel1send=new JButton("Send 1");
    channel1send.setBounds(65, 270, 100, 30);
    channel1send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            if(!(channel1Field.getText().equals("")))
            {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
               if(channel1send.isEnabled())
                 {

                    new Thread(new Channel1()).start();                                       
                 }
            }
            else
            {
                 JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Field cannot be 
                 empty", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                 JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("FAILURE");
                 dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                 dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(channel1send);

    channel2=new JLabel("Channel 2");
    channel2.setBounds(255, 140, 80, 30);
    channel2.setFont(new Font("arial",Font.BOLD,15));
    contentPane.add(channel2);

    channel2Field=new JTextField();
    channel2Field.setBounds(230, 200, 120, 30);
    channel2Field.setEnabled(true);
    contentPane.add(channel2Field);

    channel2send=new JButton("Send 2");
    channel2send.setBounds(250, 270, 80, 30);
    channel2send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(!(channel2Field.getText().equals("")))
            {
             if(channel2send.isEnabled())
             {
                 new Thread(new Channel2()).start();    
             }
             }
               else
                {
                     JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Field cannot     
                      be empty", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                     JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog("FAILURE");
                     dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                     dialog.setVisible(true);
                }
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(channel2send);

 Timer timer = new Timer();
 timer.schedule(new SayHello(), 0, 1000);
}

    class SayHello extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        try
        {   
        byte[] com=new byte[]{0x01,(byte)0xFE};
        socket=new Socket("192.168.1.3",3000);
        DataOutputStream dw=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); 
        dw.writeInt(com.length);
        dw.write(com);
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();       
        for(byte b:com)
          {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
          }
          sentmessage.append("Timer Sent -  " + sb.toString() + "\n");
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }


class Channel1 implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         try {

                String message1=channel1Field.getText();
                int msg1=Integer.parseInt(message1);
   command=new byte[]{(byte)0xFE,0x01,0x01,(byte)msg1,0x00,0x00,(byte)0xFD};
        DataOutputStream dw=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        //      dw.writeInt(command.length);
                dw.write(command);
                StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        //      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(command));
                for(byte b:command)
                  {
                    sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));

                  }
                  sentmessage.append("Client Sent to Channel 1 -  " +       
                                       sb.toString() + "\n");

            } 
            catch (IOException e1) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
                sentmessage.append("channel 1 failed to send");
            }
           finally
           {
               if(socket!=null)
               {
                   try 
                   {
                    socket.close();
                    socket=new Socket("192.168.1.3",3000);
                   } 
                   catch (IOException e1)
                   {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                   }
               }
           }
    }
}

class Channel2 implements Runnable
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            String message2=channel2Field.getText();
            int msg2=Integer.parseInt(message2);
    command=new byte[]{(byte)0xFE,0x01,0x02,(byte)msg2,0x00,0x00(byte)0xFD};
        DataOutputStream dw=new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    //      dw.writeInt(command.length);
            dw.write(command);
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

            for(byte b:command)
              {
                sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
              }
              sentmessage.append("Client Sent to Channel 2 -  " + 
                                    sb.toString() + "\n");

        } 
        catch (IOException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
            sentmessage.append("channel 2 on failed");
        }
       finally
       {
           if(socket!=null)
           {
               try {
                socket.close();
                socket=new Socket("192.168.1.3",3000);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read and apply http://sscce.org/

Comment: Try to add [``flush``](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#flush()) call after ``write``.

Comment: tried with flush also.But it is not working

Comment: how do i handle timer and button clicks simultenously

Comment: can a get a better answer to my question with the code